# How many ALUs does a single core cpu have?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture

or does depend on the model?

Comment: The number of ALU's on a chip doesn't directly correlate with performance because of factors such as architecture design, instruction set, and pipelining.

Comment: SuperUser doesn't allow questions like this any more.If you write something like this it will be downvoted and flagged as low quality

Answer (score 2):

Each CPU is different. I don't think they normally review this information but you can check with either AMD or Intel's documentation.

Comment: It would be wonderful and helpful if you could include some links along with your answer. Thankyou